# Why do I get a 'Data shape command text syntax error' when opening an Access ADP report via VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I inherited a large Access ADP project, and one of the reports is not working. Drilling into the code, I found that if I launch the report *manually* (double-clicking the report object), it opens just fine, but if I launch it through VBA code (`DoCmd.OpenReport "rptTrainingTranscript", acViewPreview`) it fails with the following error message:

*Data shape command text contains a syntax error at or near position 297 in the command. The text near the error is: " __COLRef3rsLevel0. BY primaryid AS".*

I have never seen this error before, and I am mystified as to why it is only thrown when opening the report through VBA.

Comment: Research shows various causes and solutions. One was related to a stored procedure and had to change name of a field from Shape to Shape_Code. No clue why manual opening works.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to something with the sorting and grouping in the report... Still working on it...

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this after extensive troubleshooting and thought I would post the answer here in case anyone else encounters a similar issue.

First I used **SQL tracing** tools to determine that the actual SQL requests to the server were **identical** whether I opened the report manually, or through code. From this I determined that the problem was more likely **in Microsoft Access itself**, rather than the ADP SQL emulation process.

When compact/repair and export/import didn't solve the problem, it appeared more likely to be a **report design issue** vs. file corruption.

The error message itself gave me an important clue which turned out to be key in pinpointing the problem. Note the `Level0` text in the error description...

[image]

This gave me a hunch that maybe the issue was related to the **sorting/grouping** in the report. Proceeding on that hunch, I made a copy of the report and removed all the sorting and grouping levels and the error went away!

From there it was a process of elimination to systematically work through the grouping sections and controls to pinpoint which control was causing the problem. Eventually I narrowed it down to the **control source** on a single text box.

[image]

Nothing particularly wrong with the syntax, but analyzing this in relation to the grouping levels uncovered what I believe to be the root problem.

### Mystery Solved!

A careful review of the grouping levels revealed that the control with the `DBD` field was on the footer of a higher grouping level, but was actually on a lower level in the grouping hierarchy in this report. The expression was treating it as a top-level group-by value while the grouping hierarchy was not.

Simply wrapping the field in a `MAX()` aggregate solved the error, presumably because it explicitly specified that this was an aggregate field rather than a malformed group-by field.

[image]

Exactly why it worked when running the report directly but not through code remains a mystery, but at least I understand *what* was triggering the error and how to resolve it.